# Searching a Vector of pointers in C++

Tags: c++

Working on a project for school...

I have a class `members` with 5 parameters.  I am meant to create a vector that contains pointers-to-object, which I did.  so now I have a vector `membersList` that has pointers to different members.

Each member is assigned a `memberID`.  I am trying to search the vector for a given `memberID` and return the member via a function.  I think I'm supposed to declare it up like:

```
Members* getMember (string mID);
```

But when it comes to actually writing the function, I'm lost. If the `mID` is the member ID, I can pass that to this function, and then I'll have `mID` to use in this function as a point of reference.  How do I search my vector and return the member that this ID is associated with?

Thank you!

EDIT:  DESCRIPTION OF WORK I"VE DONE SO FAR AND DIFFICULTY TRYING TO SOLVE IT:

So far, I have:

```
Members* Club::getMember (string mID)
{ return mID;}
```

which I know isn't much. The function definition is located in class `Club`, which is why that is in there. I'm having trouble figuring out how to take the member's ID number (which will be passed as a parameter to this function), and then using that to search a vector of pointers to return the associated member. I'll update as I figure things out :)

Comment: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: What you've got is nonsense. You say your function returns a pointer but them you have it returning a string. Looks to me like no thought has been put into it at all. Surely your vector needs to come into play somewhere?

Comment: sorry. fixed.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have so far.  The string that will be input it the ID number.  So for testing purposes, I just have it returning the ID number so I know nothing is getting messed up there.  I don't know how to proceed towards searching the vector, but i do know that there are members in the vector that have ID numbers.    The vector is called membersList, but I don't know how to search it!

Comment: After googling, I now have this:           Members* Club::getMember(string mID)
{
if (membersList[0]-> idCode == mID
        {return membersList [0];}
else return "NULL";
}
 Am I on the right track?  thanks    Sorry don't know how to create line breaks  :(

Answer (score 0):

The function below will accept the mID and it search in the vector to to find a match mID, if a match found it will return that pointer else it will return a 0

```
Members* Club::getMember (string mID)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(count  < membersList.size)
    {
        if(mID) == (membersList.at(count))->mID)
            return membersList.at(count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

```
std::find_if( membersList.begin(),
              membersList.end(),
              [](auto && m){return m->mID==mID;} );
```

This will return an iterator to the found match, or `membersList.end()` if no match is found.